# Datatables: cómo conservar el ID al ordenar una relación de otra tabla (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

tengo una [datatable de yajra](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) donde obtengo ciertas columnas de otras tablas, por ejemplo la columna "customer" se obtiene mediante una relación de otra tabla de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando presiono el botón ordenar por customer, los ID cambian al ID de la tabla a la que pertenece la relación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto genera errores en los botones que tengo a la derecha ya que estos ID no existen en la tabla "meos", solo en la tabla "locations" que está en la relación

¿Cómo puedo ordenarlo manteniendo el mismo ID que tenía?

Quiero mantener siempre el ID de la tabla con la que estoy, que es la tabla "meos" perteneciente a la clase "meo"

Este es mi query

```
public function query()
{
    $languageId = Auth::user()->language_id;
    return Meo::with(['businessType' => function ($query) use ($languageId) {
        $query->with(['businessTypeDescriptions' => function ($subQuery) use ($languageId) {
            $subQuery->where('language_id', '=', $languageId);
        }]);
    }])->with('location');
}
```

esta es mi función getcolumns

```
protected function getColumns()
{
    return [
        Column::make('id')->addClass('text-center')->title(__('digestReport.columns.id')),
        Column::make('location.location_name')->addClass('text-center')->title(__('digestReport.columns.customer')),
        Column::make('businessType')->addClass('text-center')->title(__('digestReport.columns.business_type'))->searchable(false),
        Column::computed('action')->exportable(false)->printable(false)->width(160)->addClass('text-center')->title(__('digestReport.columns.actions')),

    ];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solución: en el query se debe agregar el nombre de la tabla de la base de datos donde se quiere mantener los IDs, por ejemplo la tabla donde tengo los IDs que quiero mantener se llama meos en la base de datos así que debo añadir un

> ->select('meos.*');

quedando finalmente así

```
public function query()
{
    $languageId = Auth::user()->language_id;
    return Meo::with(['businessType' => function ($query) use ($languageId) {
        $query->with(['businessTypeDescriptions' => function ($subQuery) use ($languageId) {
            $subQuery->where('language_id', '=', $languageId);
        }]);
    }])->with('location')->select('meos.*');
}
```